Error 500 in Production after publishing with VS2015 for Multi-Layer .NET Framework Solution
In a solution composed of several layers:

BusinessEntity (Layer)

DTO

BeMonitorRequest.cs
...other classes...




Web (Layer)

Controllers

MonitorController.cs
...other controllers...





I am having an issue generating installation files using the 'Publish' option in VS2015. I generate the files in a specific folder and then copy and paste them into the production environment.
When I run the project from VS2015, I don't encounter any problems, but after pasting the generated deployment files into the production environment, I get a 500 error.
This error occurs when trying to fetch the endpoint called "api/monitor/getMonitorCasesByFilter". It is defined as follows in the Web layer controller:
[RoutePrefix("api/monitor")]
public class MonitorController : BaseController
{
  private readonly ISelector iSelector;
  private readonly IMonitorCase iMonitorCase;
  private readonly ITimeConverter iTimeConverter;

  public MonitorController(IMonitorCase iMonitorCase, ISelector iSelector, ITimeConverter iTimeConverter)
  {
    this.iMonitorCase = iMonitorCase;
    this.iSelector = iSelector;
    this.iTimeConverter = iTimeConverter;
  }

  [HttpGet]
  [Route("getMonitorCasesByFilter")]
  public IHttpActionResult CasesByFilter([FromUri] BeMonitorRequest request)
  {
    request.ProjectId = this.GetProject();
    request.UserName = this.GetUserName();
    List<BeMonitorCase> cases = this.iMonitorCase.GetMonitorCasesMainByFilter(request);
    return Ok(cases);
  }
}

The DTO definition is as follows:
using MyProject.BusinessEntity.DTO;

namespace MyProject.BusinessEntity.DTO
{
  public class BeMonitorRequest 
  {
    public int    ProjectId        { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDB        { get; set; }
    public string From             { get; set; }
    public string To               { get; set; }
    public string RadNumber        { get; set; }
    public string UserName         { get; set; }
    public string FullName         { get; set; }
    public int    ProcessId        { get; set; }
    public string ProcessName      { get; set; }
    public int    TaskId           { get; set; }
    public string NotificationType { get; set; }
    public int    StepTypeId       { get; set; }
    public int    WiClosed         { get; set; }
    public int    WinClosed        { get; set; }
  }
}

StartUp.cs
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyProject.Web.Startup))]
namespace MyProject.Web
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            Middleware.Configuration(app);
        }
    }
}

Middleware.cs
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyProject.Web
{
    public class Middleware
    {
        public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var container = Dependency.DependencyConfig.Configure();
            WebApiConfig.ConfigureWebApi(app, container);
        }
    }
}

DependencyConfig.cs
using MyProject.Bl;
using MyProject.Bl.Interfaces;
using MyProject.Dal;
using MyProject.Dal.Interfaces;
using MyProject.Utils;
using MyProject.Utils.Interfaces;
using MyProject.Utils.Proxies;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Unity;
 
namespace MyProject.Web.Dependency
{
    internal static class DependencyConfig
    {
        internal static IUnityContainer Configure()
        {
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
            var host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
            var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            container.RegisterType<ICacheService, MemoryCacheService>();
            container.RegisterInstance<IConfigProxyService>(new ConfigProxyService(host));
            container.RegisterType<IConfigurationCacheService, ConfigurationCacheService>();
 
            container.RegisterInstance<IDalConnection>(new DalConnection(connectionString, true));
 
            //...
            container.RegisterType<IDalMonitorCase, DalMonitorCase>();
            container.RegisterType<IMonitorCase, MonitorCase>();
            //...
 
            return container;
        }
    }
}

WebApiUnityResolver.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http.Dependencies;
using Unity;
 
namespace MyProject.Web.Dependency
{
    public class WebApiUnityResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        protected IUnityContainer container;
        public WebApiUnityResolver(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException("container");
            }
 
            this.container = container;
        }
        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            var child = container.CreateChildContainer();
            return new WebApiUnityResolver(child);
        }
 
        public void Dispose()
        {
            container.Dispose();
        }
 
        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return container.Resolve(serviceType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
 
        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            try
            {
                return container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
            }
            catch (ResolutionFailedException)
            {
                return new List<object>();
            }
        }
    }
}


Here some error samples:
In local host (it works)

In production env (it not work)

{

  "message"         : "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MonitorController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
  "exceptionType"   : "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "stackTrace"      : "
      at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"
      at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()",
  
  "innerException": {
      "message"         : "An error has occurred.",
      "exceptionMessage": "Type 'MyProject.Web.Controllers.MonitorController' does not have a default constructor",
      "exceptionType"   : "System.ArgumentException",
      "stackTrace"      : "
          at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)
          at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)
          at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)
          at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"
  }
}

Some additional information:

My PC's OS:
Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 22H2
OS Build 19045.4412

Server's OS:
Windows Server 2022 Datacenter
Version 21H2
OS Build 20348.1906

Server's IIS:
Version 10.0.20348.1

VS2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

Project Target Framework
.Net Framework 4.5.2


Things I have tried:

Cleaning and rebuilding project by project
Cleaning and rebuilding the entire solution

I don't know what else to try, please help.

I suggest you set-up a logging system so you can diagnose these issues without needing to attach a debugger - otherwise, that's your only choice now. There's little we can do to help.

@Dai I have just added more information about the error.

Do you use dependency injection? If so, this is not working in production for any reason.

@SebastianS. yes, I have just updated the post with DependencyConfig.cs and WebApiUnityResolver.cs

I cannot see a potential reason for your message in the code. Make sure you are passing the IUnityContainer from Configure method into WebApiUnityResolver and no empty object (not null, just a not configured one).

Where - or what - is calling your DependencyConfig.Configure? And where (if anywhere) are you registering your Unity IoC container with System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator ?

@Dai many thanks for your response, I have just updated the entry with StartUp.cs and Middleware.cs codes.

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 500 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

I'm guessing that your DI container is missing one of your MonitorController dependencies, so MVC then tries to fallback to the parameterless constructor, which doesn't exist.
